# Getting canvas' extent coordinates using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, extents

I'm trying get the extents of the current map canvas. CRS is 22700 BNG.

My code:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
print(canvas)

vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
extents = vLayer.extent()

print(extents)
```

Which returns

> qgis._gui.QgsMapCanvas object at 0x1198c6a68
>
> qgis._gui.QgsMapCanvas object at 0x1198c6a68

I'd like to obtain 4 numbers: xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the current map canvas' extent by running this line of code in the QGIS Python Console:

```
iface.mapCanvas().extent().toString()
```

In case that you want the extent of the active layer (as your code suggests), run this:

```
iface.activeLayer().extent().toString()
```

You could also get the individual numbers like this:

```
e = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
e.xMaximum()
e.yMaximum()
e.xMinimum()
e.yMinimum()
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Would it be just as simple to get the coordinates of a click?

Comment: @BritishSteel I think you'd need to subclass the QgsMapTool class to be able to listen to canvasPressEvent. See http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#writing-custom-map-tools for an example.